# Easier way to compare a DATE field to the date value of GETDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a field in a table `Event.EventDate` and it's of the data type `DATE` rather than `DATETIME` and then I have a view that has the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE e.EventDate >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to get all events `>=` today's **date**. The above code works, but it's ugly. I tried this ...

```
WHERE e.EventDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), 101)
```

... and this ...

```
WHERE e.EventDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 101)
```

... but those didn't work, they gave me every event `>` today's **date**. However, even if the above worked, it's still ugly.

Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`WHERE e.EventDate >= cast(getdate() as date)`

To cast getdate() into a date time. It's a clean way in SQL Server 2008 and up to strip out the time portion of a datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

Using Shan Plourde's method is certainly cleaner and quicker, but for the more general case when you want to round a `datetime` to a particular time interval, I use

```
dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,[datetime column]),0)
```

where `dd` stands for day, and can be replaced with `mm` (month), `hh` (hour), `mi` (minute), and probably others.

If you want to get fancy and round to, say, 15 minute intervals, you can use

```
dateadd(mi, 
        -datepart(mi,[datetime column])%15,
        dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,[datetime column]),0)
        )
```

where `%` is the modulo operator. You'll get wacky results for this if you don't use an interval that divides 60 evenly.